# XPath - exclude descendants of specific selector

Tags: xpath

I have following markup (schema.org attributes included):

```html
<body>
  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Foo">
    <div>
      <div itemname="name">
        Foo scoped name
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Bar">
        <div>
          <div itemname="name">
            Bar scoped name
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I need to select (presumably by xpath as css selectors won't be enough for the task) divs that have `itemname="name"` in `http://schema.org/Foo` scope but not those that have another element with `itemscope` attribute ascending them.

So in example provided I need to select only "Foo scoped name", but not "Bar scoped name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like :

```
//div[@itemname="name"][ancestor::div[@itemscope][1][@itemtype="http://schema.org/Foo"]]
```

Look for a `div` element with a specific attribute value (`@itemname="name"`). Its first `div` ancestor  (with `@itemscope` attribute) contains also a specific `@itemtype` attribute value (`http://schema.org/Foo`).

Output : `<div itemname="name">   Foo scoped name </div>`